# issues with fstream in payroll project

Tags: c++, oop

I am having issues with a payroll project. We are using fstream to write and read from 2 separate files. Whenever we run the add records and answer no to the main menu question the program exits with code 0, yet nothing is added to the files. If we say yes to return to the main menu and try and add another record we exit with code 5 which is the exit code for a failure on the employee-details.dat file. Both files are in the directory and have worked before we did some modifications and started using fstream.

Any tips on which direction to take?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class payroll
{
private:
    char empnum[10];
    string empfirstname;
    string emplastname;
    char empsin[9];
    char empdob[10];
    char empphone[15];
    string empstreet;
    string empcity;
    string empprovince;
    string empcountry;
    string empstatus;       //Employee status. EX: Terminated, On leave, Active etc.
    double empsalaryei;
    double empsalaryfedtax;
    double empsalarycpp;
    double empsalarynet;
    double empsalarygross;
    double empsalaryprovtax;

public: 
    void addrec(void);
    void modrec(void);
    void viewrec(void);
    void exit1(void);
};

payroll rec;
payroll emp;
bool check = false;
bool filecheck1 = false;
bool filecheck2 = false;
fstream fileemp;
fstream filesal;


void mainmenu()
{

    system("CLS");
    char ch;

    do
    {
        if (check == true)
        {
            system("CLS");
            ch=0;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"1. Add an employee\n";
            cout<<"2. Modify employee record\n";
            cout<<"3. View employee record\n";
            cout<<"0. Exit\n";
            cout<<"Please choose an item: ";
            cin>>ch;
        }

        switch(ch)
        {
            case '1':
                emp.addrec();
                break;

            case '2':
                emp.modrec();
                break;

            case '3':
                emp.viewrec();
                break;

            case '0':
                emp.exit1();

        }
    }while(ch !=0);

}

int main()
{
    if (check==false)
    {
        mainmenu();
    }else{
        exit(25);
    }
}

void openfiles()
{
    string filename1 = "employee-details1.dat";
    string filename2 = "payroll-info.dat";

    fileemp.open(filename1.c_str(), ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    filecheck1 = true;
    if(fileemp.fail())
    {
        cout <<"\nSorry the Employee file was not opened"<< "\nPlease check that the file exists" << endl;
        exit(5);
    }

    filesal.open(filename2.c_str(), ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    filecheck2 = true;
    if(filesal.fail())
    {
        cout << "\nSorry the Salary file was not opened"<< "\nPlease check that the file exists" << endl;
        exit(10);
    }
}



void payroll::addrec(void)          //Record adding
{
    system("CLS");
    char userinputadd = ' ';
    check = false;

    if ((filecheck1 == false) && (filecheck2 == false))     //check if our files are open
    {
        openfiles();            //open both of our data files before the user chooses
    }                   

    fileemp.seekp(0L,ios::end);     //go to the end of the employee data file
    filesal.seekp(0L,ios::end);     //go to the end of the salary file
    cout << "Please Enter the Employee Number: ";
    cin>>rec.empnum;
    cin.clear();
    cout << "\nPlease Enter the Employee's First Name: ";
    cin>>rec.empfirstname;
    cin.clear();
    cout << "\nPlease Enter the Employee's Last Name: ";
    cin>>rec.emplastname;
    cin.clear();
    cout << "\nPlease Enter the Employee's Date of Birth (mmddyyyy): ";
    cin>>rec.empdob;
    cin.clear();
    cout << "\nPlease Enter the Employee's Social Insurance Number: ";
    cin>>rec.empsin;
    cin.clear();
    cout << "\nPlease Enter the Employee's Phone Number: ";
    cin>>rec.empphone;
    cin.clear();
    cout << "\nPlease Enter the Employee's Address: ";
    cin>>rec.empstreet;
    cin.clear();
    cout << "\nPlease Enter the Employee's City: ";
    cin>>rec.empcity;
    cin.clear();
    cout << "\nPlease Enter the Employee's Province: ";
    cin>>rec.empprovince;
    cin.clear();
    cout << "\nPlease Enter the Employee's Country: ";
    cin>>rec.empcountry;
    cin.clear();
    cout<<"\nPlease Enter the Employee's Status: ";
    cin>>rec.empstatus;
    cin.clear();
    cout << "\nPlease Enter the Employee's Weekly Gross Salary: ";
    cin >> rec.empsalarygross;
    cin.clear();

    rec.empsalaryei = rec.empsalarygross * 0.0178;
    rec.empsalarycpp = (rec.empsalarygross-134.61)*0.0495;
    rec.empsalaryfedtax = rec.empsalarygross * 0.15;
    rec.empsalaryprovtax = rec.empsalarygross*0.0505;
    rec.empsalarynet = rec.empsalarygross-rec.empsalaryei-rec.empsalarycpp-rec.empsalaryfedtax-rec.empsalaryprovtax;



    fileemp<<rec.empnum<<","<<rec.empfirstname<<","<<rec.emplastname<<","<<rec.empdob<<","<<rec.empsin<<","<<rec.empphone<<","<<rec.empstreet<<","<<rec.empcity<<","<<rec.empprovince<<","<<rec.empcountry<<"0L";
    filesal<<rec.empnum<<","<<rec.empsalaryei<<","<<rec.empsalarycpp<<","<<rec.empsalaryfedtax<<","<<rec.empsalaryprovtax<<","<<rec.empsalarynet<<"0L";
    cin.clear();

    cout<<"Press any key to the main menu.... ";
    getch();
    mainmenu();
}

void payroll::modrec(void)          //Record Modification
{
    system("CLS");
    int empmodnum=0;
    check = false;
    char userinputmod = ' ';

    cout<<"\nEnter the employee number for the record you would like to modify: ";
    cin>>empmodnum;


    cout<<"Press any key to the main menu.... ";
    getch();
    mainmenu();
}

void payroll::viewrec(void)         //Record viewing
{
    int ch1 = 0;
    int i=0;
    system("CLS");
    check = false;
    char userinputview = ' ';
    if ((filecheck1 == false) && (filecheck2 == false))
    {
        openfiles();            //open both of our data files before the user chooses
    }

    cout <<"Which file would you like to view?"
    <<"\n1) Employee Details"
    <<"\n2) Employee Salary Info\n";
    cin >> ch1;

    if(ch1==1)
    {
        i=0;
        fileemp.seekg(0L,ios::beg);
        cout<<"\nList of Records in the Employee Data file"<<endl<<endl;


        while(fileemp.read((char*)&rec,sizeof(rec)))
        {
            cout<<endl<<"Record#"<<""<<i++<<setw(4)<<rec.empnum<<setw(10)
            <<rec.empfirstname<<setw(20)<<rec.emplastname<<setw(30)
            <<rec.empsin<<setw(9)<<rec.empdob<<setw(10)<<rec.empphone<<setw(15)
            <<rec.empstreet<<setw(25)<<rec.empcity<<setw(15)<<rec.empprovince<<setw(15)
            <<rec.empcountry<<setw(15)<<rec.empstatus<<setw(10)
            <<endl;
        }

        if (i==0)
        {
            cin.clear();
            cout <<"\nNO RECORDS EXIST";
            cout <<"\nPress any key to continue...";
            getch();
        }else{
            cin.clear();
            cout<<endl<<"Press any key...";
            getch();
        }
    }else if(ch1==2)
    {
        i=0;
        filesal.seekg(0L,ios::beg);
        cout <<"\nList of Records in the Employee Salary file"<<endl<<endl;

        while(filesal.read((char*)&rec,sizeof(rec)))
        {
            cout <<endl<<"Record#"<<""<<i++<<setw(4)
            <<rec.empnum<<setw(10)<<rec.empsalarygross<<setw(15)
            <<rec.empsalaryei<<setw(10)<<rec.empsalarycpp<<setw(10)
            <<rec.empsalaryfedtax<<setw(10)<<rec.empsalaryprovtax<<setw(10)
            <<rec.empsalarynet<<setw(10)
            <<endl;
        }
        if (i==0)
        {
            cout <<"\nNO RECORDS EXIST";
            cout <<"\nPress any key to continue...";
            getch();
            mainmenu();
        }else{
            cout<<endl<<"Press any key...";
            getch();
            mainmenu();
        }
    }
}

void payroll::exit1(void)
{
    fileemp.close();
    filesal.close();
    filecheck1 = false;
    filecheck2 = false;
    check = true;
}
```

Comment: You are not allowed to recursively call main() (any other function is fine but not main). But saying that a loop would probably be a better idea.

Comment: You should reduce this code; simplify it as much as you can, testing at every step, and see how simple you can get it while still reproducing the behavior. The bug may become obvious along the way, and if not you can post the results and we'll have a lot less to comb through.

Comment: You are mixing C stdio and C++ streams, which is a bad thing. The call to `fflush(stdin)` won't do anything to `std::cin`.

Comment: Why are you calling `main()` in `payroll::viewrec()`?  Program control and termination should be handled outside of the `payroll` class.

Comment: Use `tolower` or `toupper`, which will eliminate the need to compare for uppercase and lowercase. Something like `if (tolower(userinputadd) == 'y')`.

Comment: Simplify your life:  replace the `char` arrays with `std::string`.  Save yourself a lot of pain and use one or the other but not both; prefer `std::string`

Comment: I appreciate everyones help, i have just updated the code with the changes i have made so far. Once i get a chance i will make all the above changes as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the function **void openfiles()**, you have used

```
fileemp.open(filename1.c_str(), ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary||ios::app);
.
.
.
.
filesal.open(filename2.c_str(), ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary||ios::app);
```

It should be

```
fileemp.open(filename1.c_str(), ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary|ios::app);
.
.
.
.
filesal.open(filename2.c_str(), ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary|ios::app);
```

After this change, I compiled it and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: sorry i cannot catch the difference nims.

Comment: @Dani you wrote ios::binary||ios::app      ("||")
it should be    ios::binary|ios::app       ("|")

Comment: haha, that would explain why when i removed iOS::app it worked :P